# AngularJS: How to write Jasmine test for form submit?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, submit, form-submit, karma-jasmine

I want to auto-submit a form which is in the directive template. Below is the directive code for the same:

```
link: function(scope, el) {
    $timeout(function() {
       el.submit();
    });
}
```

How to write Jasmine test for this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by spying on the submit function and delegating the call to the supplied function.

This goes in beforeEach block:-

```
element = angular.element(html);
compiledDirective = _$compile_(element)($scope);
$scope.$digest();
form = element[0];
spyOn(form, 'submit').and.callFake(function() {
    return false;
});
```

And then test your code for submit in the it() function:-

```
it('check if it submits the form', function() {
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(form.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```